# Unable to run my app from Android Gingerbread 2.3.9 Phone

Tags: android

I am using Android 10 Gingerbread 2.3.9 version . I have tested my app on Emulator using Eclipse it works fine . Now I want to test my app on real device. For that I have googled a lot and found that we need to Download the Google USB Driver package from SDK Manager.

I have downloaded and Update my driver from Device manager then it says Your driver is Updated Successfully. When I plug my Phone to PC in device manager I got 2 options like Spreadtrum Phone and  a Android Phone I have updated the driver for Android Phone and for the Spreadtrum Phone it shows a Yellow bar near left bottom corner. I dono what it was and googled to find a driver to update it also but could not figured out. I left that part and tried in another way.

I have connected my Phone to my PC and then copy the .apk file into my SD Card and then unplug the cable from my pc. then I click on my .apk file. I was able to run. but the problem is with when 
I try to debug the app from eclipse when phone is connected. I have chosen the option as "Allow me to Pick a device every time" from Run Configurations". But I am unable to see my device in my Devices list also I tried from Command prompt "adb devices" it is not listed my phone which I connected.  I have Checked 'Unknown Resources" and also Checked " Use Debugging" in Developement menu option. but nothing solves my problem.

I have tried a lot of code samples and every one is doing in the same way but I could not figure out the problem. 
Please friends tell me what is the problem as I am not able to debug from my eclipse I can't figure out the problem from LogCat also.

Thanks
Ganesh

Comment: when you tried with adb devices, are you able to see at least your emulator in that list?

Comment: yes I am able to see my emulator which I was running from command prompt. @Brinda-user1594986

Comment: are you getting "?????" instead of phone name?

Comment: when I use this command adb devices it simply shows "List of attached devices" but nothing appears below I have selected "USB Debugging and under USB Settings I have selected USB Mass Storage". and my app targets API 10 and my phone is also API 10 does this cause any compatability issues @Brinda-user1594986

Comment: try adb device ; adb kill-server ; adb start-server; and use adb devices, it may list your devices.

Comment: yeah I have tried that also but still unable to detect my device and small thing when I connect my phone to pc. I donot got any option to see rather when I look at Device manager I have got a Android Phone and another Spreadtrum Phone. I have updated the driver Google USB Driver downloaded from SDK Manager but the same thing is happens

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24115/discussion-between-ganesh-and-brinda-user1594986)

Comment: @Brinda-user1594986 come to [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24115/discussion-between-ganesh-and-brinda-user1594986)